# Enter data in Javascript form using Selenium Golang

Tags: go, selenium-webdriver, proxy, javascript-objects, forms-authentication

I need to add a proxy to my Web Driver, I am able to set a proxy IP and port, but no username and password. So there's a javascript form opens. Of course it is not inside HTML, so I am wondering how can  I enter username and password there.

[image: Here is how my javascript form looking like]

I found a form filling using Zennoposter service on C# and I tried to make function ExecuteScript with my driver.
`instance.setAuthorizationPolicy("ok", "username", "password");`
But of course the compiler returns an error that there is no defined instance. Instance is part of Zennoposter library, but not Selenium.

ChatGPT says to find a CSS selector of the form, but I don't know any part of HTML code of that JavaScript form.

Also I tried function SendKeys but it doesn't work too.